# Difference between "spearhead" and "lead"

Tags: meaning, difference

> New onsite graduate programs are bringing DePaul through the door at
>   some of the area’s most prominent employers. This summer, two
>   corporate onsite cohorts began with the delivery of a Master of
>   Business Administration degree program at Medline, a major
>   manufacturer and distributor of healthcare supplies, and a Master of
>   Public Health degree program at Lurie Children’s Hospital—resulting in
>   70 new graduate students and $3.2 million in revenue over the duration
>   of the program.   These partnerships were **spearheaded** by EMM’s
>   Corporate and Employer Outreach (CEO) initiative.
>
> From
>   https://offices.depaul.edu/enrollment-management-marketing/enrollment-matters/Pages/ceo-launches-corporate-onsite-graduate-programs.aspx

Could you explain the connotation of ‘spearhead” here?  How is it different from “lead”?

> spearhead /ˈspiɚˌhɛd/ verb
>
> : to be the leader of (something, such as a political movement)
>
> http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/spearhead

Here is research I have done. I am not sure if it is correct.

> Spearheaded
>
> Meaning: To spearhead means to be the leader of something. But more
>   important is the word's connotation. This word just oozes **leadership,
>   taking charge,  and being a self-starter.**
>
> https://www.pongoresume.com/blogPosts/152/5-power-words-to-make-your-resume-get-noticed.cfm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you say, "Spearhead" basically means exactly the same as "lead" but with more militaristic, dynamic, positive overtones.

In theory, one could lead a project from a position of fear, whereas spearheading suggests far more passion and drive.

Comment: I think Spearhead indicates a narrow head that others will follow afterwards (shaped like a spear+shaft). Lead could be broader - boomerang shaped

Comment: @Smock  Do you have any evidence for that - it doesn't match with my experience.

Comment: Spearhead here in this context given as a passionate way but it still holds the meaning of a narrow mind. Where lead is wider in thinking and carefull with actions.